# Permissions troubles with Library folder in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, backup, permissions, time-machine

Here is my sad story.

In my macbook pro I have 2 disks and Time Capsule. There are SSD with system and apps and HDD with user folder. The other day my HDD disk was totaly broken. I bought new one and replace it.

After that I couldn't log in because user folder was on the old disk. I was started recovery from Time Capsule which proposed me to select disk for restory system. I choosen SSD. System was restored but HDD still empty. Same situation - system work but there is no user folder. I don't give up.

Go to the Single User! Cmd+S on system start. Creating new user, loggin, and goes to Time Capsule with **Finder**. Yes, there is my user folder. Copy them to my new HDD, rebooting.

There are my icons on desktop, my docs. Looks good. Trying to launch some apps. Another errors...when this stoped? A lot of apps tell me, that haven't permissions to write some files.

For example Skype said that he can't write to ***/Volumes/Storage/den/Library/Application Support/Skype/Skype.pid***,

Firefox ***didn't found profile,***

Photoshop ***Could not initialize Photoshop failed to initialize CoolType*** 
and many other...

But if we take a look on permission of skype.pid file:

[image]

it looks good.

What I **tryed**:

- Permission repair (disk utility)
- ACL permission repair (*resetpassword* from recovery menu)

Answer (score 2):

Try [BatChmod](http://www.lagentesoft.com/batchmod/index.html) to set permissions temporarily on whatever you cannot access.

Use Disk Utility to Repair Permissions when you are done moving/copying things.